# Center heading over the border between columns in a table

Tags: tables

I have a table that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{heading} \\
\toprule
string & much longer string long  \\
string & much longer string long  \\
string & much longer string long  \\
string & much longer string long  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

"heading" looks like it is a heading only of the second column. I would like it to be centered over the split between both columns so that it is clear that this is not the case. Alternative opinions about how to typeset this are also welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space between two columns usually consists of the right `\tabcolsep` of the first column and the left `\tabcolsep` of the second column.
The first column is already right-aligned, `\rlap` prints to the right, `\kern\tabcolsep` moves to the place between the two columns and `\makebox[0pt]` centers the text without occupying space for TeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \rlap{\kern\tabcolsep\makebox[0pt]{heading}} \\
  % variant:
  % \rlap{\makebox[2\tabcolsep]{heading}} \\
\toprule
string & much longer string long  \\
string & much longer string long  \\
string & much longer string long  \\
string & much longer string long  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Alternative:**

- Depending on the circumstances, the table might not need a "heading", because it can be put into the table caption.

Comment: No idea how you did it, but it works beautifully. I will consider the alternative too!